# how to give css to tab headings in react?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I wan't to give different css to the active tabs.

[image]

Comment: How do you store the information of the active tab?

Comment: Use states and set them to true or false depending upon the onClick event of the two tabs. Render different styles using conditional operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to have a state to toggle between active and inactive state of the tabs.

```
this.state = {
         activeTab: 0
      }
```

And then use this state variable to add css conditionally as bellow.

```
onClickHanlder = (tabIndex) => {
  this.setState({activeTab: tabIndex});
}

render(){
  return(
    ...
    <a className="nav-lin focus" style={this.state.activeTab === 0 ? {color:"#000"} : {color:"#fff"}}  onClick={onClickHandler(0)} ...></a>

    ...
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React we use `className` instead of `class`, to add active class you can add condition in string as:

```
<a className=`nav-lin focus ${active === '1' ? 'active' : '' } onClick={} ...></a>`
```